# Kali-Linux dual boot doesn't work well: I cannot choose the operating system at boottime

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot

I installed Kali Linux as dual boot and it works well, i.e. I had both Windows 10 and Kali Linux and before loading the operating system, the bootloader asks for the operating system to load.

Now, 5 days ago, I reinstalled Windows 10 and formatted the disk which contains Windows 10. I successfully installed it and it's working well.

The problem is that now, it no longer asks about which operating system I want to choose. It systematically loads Windows 10, so I no longer have a working dual boot.

One important thing: I installed Kali Linux on a separate drive. I made another drive (taking space from "drive D" and not from the Windows drive which is "drive C").  That drive which I made only for Kali Linux didn't get formatted during the reinstallation of Windows 10.

sorry about I give you pain to read the such a long article but I have to clear the overall scenario

Comment: lgeorget dear i visit your provided link but  its about unix not linux but before trying the provided solution I get confused where to run these commands either on cmd or on some other and in accepted solution he described to use "sudo" comand for mac and root for other but in cmd  where is root

Comment: The other question is about Ubuntu... How is that not Linux?

Comment: I am beginner so  i don't know many of terms. but i didn't use ubuntu to works as dual boot. But now i am confused where to run those commands that's given in accepted answer in your provided link

Comment: If you're such a beginner, you might want to use a Linux *other than* Kali.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way download [Supergrudisk or Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) and restore grub.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to manually select the Linux entry from the bootloader, and following the steps mentioned below.

- After you have successfully logged in to your OS manually selecting through the bootloader, execute these commands as sudo user. (Using sudo)
- `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- `grub-install /dev/sda`